# How to convert dd/MM/yyyy date to "Fri Mar 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"

Tags: angularjs, date

is there any way to convert formatted date to original date string in angular JS?

Here is the code that I have tried :

```
$scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate = $filter('date')($scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

now i want to convert dd/MM/yyyy to original date string.

i tried `new Date($scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate)`

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried yet. We are not here to write code for you, rather we are here to help you in your problem

Comment: in the question please, not as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   var startdate=$scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate
   var splitarry=startdate.split("/"); 
   var month="splitarray[1]; 
   var day=splitarray[0]; 
   var year =split(array[1]); 
   var newDateobj=new Date("month+"/"+day+"/"+year); 
    alert(newDateobj+"");
```

Comment: I tried like this                                                                                               var startdate = $scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate;
 alert(new Date(startdate)); and it gives invalid date. where startdate = "17/03/2016"

Comment: alert $scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate  this what is the output?

Comment: here is the output "17/03/2016"

Comment: when you execute alert(new Date(startdate));  what is the output?

Comment: when i execute alert it popup "Invalid Date"

Comment: use this $filter('date')($scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate, 'medium'); or $filter('date')($scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD');

Comment: then use  var datevar=$scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate
   alert(new Date(datevar));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106546/discussion-between-dkc007-and-hassan-tariq).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) fro date formatting like as-

```
var date=    moment(new Date($scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate)).format();
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
//parse a date in dd/mm/yyyy format
function parseDate(input) {
   var parts = input.split('/');
   return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
}

alert(parseDate($scope.sprintListData.sprintDate.startSprintDate));
```

Please refer to this link for more detailed answer:
[Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)